# Checking input to see if its a double in Java

Tags: java, exception

I am working on creating code that asks for 2 numbers and then adds them up/multipies/divides. I managed to get this to work but I encountered a small problem.

This is the part of the code thats bugging me:

```
double number1 = 0;
do {
    try {
        System.out.print("First number: ");
        number1 = input.nextDouble();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.print("This is not a number. ");
    }
    input.nextLine();
} while (number1 == 0);
```

It works fine for what I am intending to do, which is ask for a number. If the user does not input a number, it catches the exception and prevents it from just exiting.

```
while (number1 == 0);
```

This is what I used to test if the try and catch worked as intended, but of course means number1 can not be 0 or it will not stop and keep asking for a number.

I want it to keep asking for input as long as a double is not entered, what do I replace?

Because this is a assigment, I have to keep asking for a **double**, if its better not to use the exception, that is acceptable. But it has to assign a number to number1 that I can use later on in the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, here is how you can modify your code to make it work - you can add a `boolean` flag to indicate that the loop has succeeded:

```
double number1 = 0;
boolean success;
do {
    success = true;
    try {
        System.out.print("First number: ");
        number1 = input.nextDouble();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.print("This is not a number. ");
        success = false;
    }
    input.nextLine();
} while (!success);
```

Next, should rework your code to avoid catching exceptions by calling `hasNextDouble` before calling `nextDouble`:

```
double number1 = 0;
while(true) {
    System.out.print("First number: ");
    if (input.hasNextDouble()) {
        number1 = input.nextDouble(); // This will not throw an exception
        break;
    }
    System.out.print("This is not a number. ");
    input.nextLine();        
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I added in the first part to my own code and that fixed the obvious issue I had, but I am not sure how the second part works. Im assuming its better to not catch exceptions at all?

Comment: @DenzelSimson There is no general answer of what's "better", you decide on a case-by-case basis. When you ask user for input, you expect them to enter wrong things every now an then, so you should not catch exceptions, but proactively check for correct input. When you read a file in fixed format that is generated automatically, you don't expect incorrect data, and you cannot go back and tell the user to give you a different input, so you catch exceptions, or let them through to terminate the program.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `parseDouble` function offered by the `Double` class if you are okay with catching an exception.

A simple code snippet that accomplishes this would be

```
public class AcceptDouble {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double number1 = 0;

        while(true){
            try {
                number1 = Double.parseDouble(sc.next());
                System.out.println("Got: " + number1);
                // DO WHAT YOU WANT WITH NUMBER1
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException timeToBreak) {
                System.out.println("Time to break");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This keeps accepting new input as long as a valid number is entered. A sample output snippet attached for reference

```
34
Got: 34.0
23
Got: 23.0
12
Got: 12.0
end
Time to break
```